# How TypeOrm resolve relations

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am new to NestJs and TypeOrm. When i am walking through the docs, I am quite confused about the relation in TypeOrm. How does TypeOrm resolve the relation like @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToMany ?

I did tried the other tutorial but it wasn't clear